# How to replace a UILabel with a UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have a UILabel that is nested inside of a StackView, and I am needing to create a UIView that will take up the exact same position on the screen as the UILabel did, and then hide the UILabel (this is a premium portion of an app, so if it's the free version I need to replace the data with a lock icon).  My code below creates the view but it's positioning is far to the bottom right of where the label is. How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

```
                let testView = UIView()
                testView.frame = CGRect(x: hrrLabel.frame.origin.x, y: hrrLabel.frame.origin.y, width: hrrLabel.frame.width, height: hrrLabel.frame.height)
                testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                hrrLabel.isHidden = true
                hrrLabel.addSubview(testView)
```

Comment: How is the label created?  Does it have constraints?

Comment: Why not just make the view a subview of the label with its frame equal to the label bounds? That way it covers the label and no harm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the `testView` in your `hrrLabel`'s bounds. (Assuming the view you want to place on TOP is the `testView` -- not entirely sure which view is suppose to be which).

```
let testView = UIView()
testView.frame = hrrLabel.bounds //Bounds here, not frame
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
hrrLabel.isHidden = true
hrrLabel.addSubview(testView)

//Hide view without hiding subviews
hrrLabel.backgroundColor = hrrLabel.backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(alpha: 0)
//hrrLabel.isHidden = true
```

Lookup the difference between `CGRect.bounds` and `CGRect.frame` and it will make creating subviews much easier.

Comment: Thanks this works well, the isHidden line doesn't work I'm assuming because hiding a view also hides it's subviews.  However I just changed `hrrLabel.text = " "` and achieved the same effect.

Comment: Look at edit to hide a view without hiding subviews